# Why does pandas.to_csv make a bigger file than xlsx

Tags: python, pandas

My code currently grabs some workbooks from the our server and copies them a another location, where I get pandas to read each file (100 workbooks), filter down a certain column then output the filtered data as a .csv. It takes 788 seconds to run over the 100 workbooks (all circa 8mb) and outputs a csv (all 10mb). I was just wondering why the filtered workbook data, with less rows would be a bigger workbook?

The difference in the dataset between the xlsx and csv's is about 2000 rows out of the total 220,000 rows.

Here's the code;

```
def csvofnoline(homedir):
    for filename in os.listdir(homedir):
        if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
            fName = os.path.join(homedir,'\',filename)
            fBase = os.path.basename(fName)
            fRaw = os.path.splitext(fBase)[0]
            df = pd.read_excel(fName, index = False)
            df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
            dfblanks = df[pd.isnull(df['Data Line'])] 
            dfblanks.to_csv(path_or_buf=os.path.join(homedir,'\',fRaw,"_NLA_.csv"), header = True, index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlsx` is a compressed (zipped) format.